# Go (c *net.UnixConn) ReadFrom() fails to fire after some period (hours, days)

Tags: go, unix-socket

I have a server process that does lots of things. One of those is receiving UNIX datagram packets. After a while it stops receiving them, while the rest of the server's functionality (appears) to continue just fine.

The socket was established with:

```
unixSock, err := net.ListenUnixgram("unixgram", &net.UnixAddr{Name: "/tmp/controller_socket"})
```

and there is a loop receiving messages that looks like this:

```
func packetHandler(self *controller, c net.PacketConn) {
    msg := make([]byte, MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE)
    for {
        msg = msg[:cap(msg)]
        n, addr, err := c.ReadFrom(msg)
        if err == io.EOF {
            return
        }
        if n > 0 {
            gotMessage(self, msg[:n], addr)
        }
    }
}
```

After the server starts this all runs just fine. Then, after some time (maybe a day or more) sending processes fail to send to the socket, as illustrated by this command:

```
$ echo foo | socat - UNIX-SENDTO:/tmp/controller_socket
2022/10/11 10:50:34 socat[1776033] E sendto(5, 0x55ae7454f000, 4, 0, AF=1 "/tmp/controller_socket", 24): Connection refused
```

netstat confirms that the socket is being listened on and with a receive queue of length 2:

```
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    46822161 /tmp/controller_socket
```

and looking at the server process using `/proc` we see that fd=3 is indeed for that socket:

```
3 -> 'socket:[46822161]'
```

If I attach a debugger to the server process I can see a goroutine that is indeed attempting to read from the socket. It is blocked in `c.ReadFrom()` and setting a breakpoint on the following line confirms that it is not returning with an unhandled error. The debugger shows that `c.(*net.UnixConn).conn.fd.pfd.Sysfd == 3`.

[image: Stack trace in debugger]

In summary:

- There is a UNIX datagram listener opened by the server process.
- There is a goroutine in that process blocked on receive on that listener.
- Senders get "Connection refused".

What has gone wrong?

go version go1.18.1 linux/amd64

Comment: You are only checking for `io.EOF`, there are of course other errors that you could get. If you get anything besides EOF you go into a busy loop.

Comment: Yes, there are probably others that should be checked for. But as I said, in this instance I did check that that was not the case by using a debugger breakpoint.

Comment: I have not idea what Go does between ReadFrom() and OS recvfrom(). Use strace or truss (depending on your OS) to see what happens on system call interface, for example:
    `strace -v -tt -f -p <serverpid> -e trace=socket,bind,send,sendto,recv,recvfrom,shutdown'
before the socket blocks